# Passing Multiple parameters as catch them

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom, mern

I'm trying to pass 'slug' in the URL by adding 'id' and 'type'.

Code:

```
`/${category.slug}?cid=${category._id}&type=${category.type}`   
 <Route path="/:slug" element={<ProductListPage />} />
```

URL

```
http://localhost:3000/Samsung-3whQlbAYpm?cid=61ed050cab3efd275d49efd6&type=store
```

Problem : However, in the useParam() I received only slug not addition parameters such as 'cid' and 'type'

For example,

```
let params = useParams();
```

Its params have only 'slug' value which is 'Samsung-3whQlbAYpm'

How can I get addition value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `useParams` hook only gets you the defined route params from the path part of the URL. If you want to access the queryString then use the [`useSearchParams`](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#usesearchparams) hook from `react-router-dom`.

```
const [searchParams] = useSearchParams();

const cid = searchParams.get("cid");
const type = searchParams.get("type");
```

If you happen to still be using `react-router-dom` v5 then use the `location` object to get the `search` string to be passed to a `URLSearchParams` constructor.

```
const { search } = useLocation();
const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(search);
```